# Prove that $x_n=e^{x_{n-1}-2}$ is unbounded for $x_0>4$.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that $x_n=e^{x_{n-1}-2}$ is unbounded for $x_0>4$ (More exactly, for $x_0>p$ where $p$ is the greatest fixed point of $e^{x-2}$).

Let $k>0$. I want to show that there exists some $N$ such that $x_N>k$ and since $x_N$ is increasing I'll be done then.

How do I find that $N$?

Comment: Just show that $x_n - x_{n-1} > c$ for some positive constant $c$.  If you had to do this for $x_0 > p$ it would be a little more subtle since there is no such constant $c$ that works for all initial choices of $x_0$, but it still is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of $e^{x-2}-x$ is $e^{x-2}-1$, so $e^{x-2}-x$  is clearly increasing in $(3,\infty)$. Moreover it is positive at $4$, so it is positive in $(4,\infty)$.

From here let $x_1-x_0=\delta$. We have $0<\delta$ and we have $\delta=x_1-x_0\leq x_2-x_1\leq x_3-x_2\dots $.

Therefore $x_n\geq x_0+(n-1)\delta$. So taking $N=\lceil \frac{k}{\delta}+1 \rceil$ does the trick.

Comment: You probably want a floor or ceil in there somewhere :)

Comment: Right, thanks ${}{}{}$.

Comment: This argument actually works for any $x_0 > p$, since the same method shows $e^{x-2}-x$ is positive in $(p,\infty)$.